# How to read older login info using the "last" command?

Tags: command-line

The `last` command may show too few lines of user login info, truncated by when the “wtmp begins”.

If I want to get as much as possible `last` info (e.g., to see if my system was accessed from any unknown/suspicious IP using my username), how can I output the older “last” info?

If I use `last -2000`, intending to see 2000 lines of output, but the command may only return just a few lines, anything that happened before the “wtmp begins” would be truncated.)

Just wondering somehow if it is possible to output as many lines of login info as possible.

Comment: `last -o` might help. The man page says it reads old wtmp files. But on my system it doesn't give much info. Although, `wtmp begins` sets to Jan 1 1970.

Comment: that's funny.  if you have more logins since 1970 than what are shown in your log, then some setting may be incorrect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `last` command uses the binary file `/var/log/wtmp` to show a listing of last logged in users.

But `/var/log/wtmp` is a rotated file where old entries are archived into `/var/log/wtmp.x` where x is a digit `[0-9]`.

So If you need to look deeper in the login history, try to open one of those files:

```
last -2000 -f /var/log/wtmp.1 | less
```

Comment: To read 2000 line in terminal it is better to pass it to `less` as
`last -2000 -f /var/log/wtmp.1| less`, +1 for nice answer

Comment: Good idea, thanks @souravc. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so very much!  I noticed that the wtmp.1 file was automatically gzipped into wtmp.1.gz file,  so I unzipped it, and used "last -f" to read, that is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.  Btw, the wtmp.1 seems still too recent, and I only have wtmp1 file (no other files such as wtmp2 etc in /var/log), if I want my system to store more info, how can I change the default system setting for this purpose?

Comment: Please create a new question to cover how many rotations should be archived.

Answer (score 5):

If the last `-f /var/log/wtmp.1` doesn't give any output this can be because e.g. the record length has changed in a newer version.

A simply option would be then to use utmpdump instead:

```
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp.1  | less
```

Oh, and `less` can be quitted using <kbd>q</kbd> (from "quit" ;-) )

Comment: Have your first 10 points ever, 1 year later!

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Logs in

```
/var/log/wtmp.1
```

are constrained.

Ubuntu **16** and probably **17** have mechanism of deleting logs older than one month. To configure this behavior  you should edit:

```
/etc/logrotate.conf
```

More info:

> [Access to logs of startup and shut down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856199/access-to-logs-of-startup-and-shut-down)

Comment: +1 for /etc/logrotate.conf