# Command or script to get user login details of last 6 months

Tags: 14.04, command-line, login, last-command

I need to get the details of the users logged in from last 6 months to analyze and to increase the cpu of my server. I'm tried the command **last -a** but it is not giving the complete results. Anyone please help me to get the details of users logged in from last 6 months.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

#### Newer versions

You can use `-s` option:

```
last -s  -6month
```

> Display the state of logins since the specified time.

use `-t` to specify until another date if you like.

If you receive a message like:

```
wtmp begins Tue Apr ...
```

it means that "logrotate" has removed your log files so you don't have access to use them.

#### for older versions you should specify full time:

```
last -t 20170101000000
```

Comment: If I try that command with -s option, it is throwing error like invalid option

Comment: last: invalid option -- 's' and there no option -s in man page.

Comment: What is the output of `last -V`?

Comment: Same as above. last: invalid option -- 'V'

Comment: Is this work for you? `last --time-format=iso | grep "2017-0[0-6]"`

Comment: No.                                     last: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: last [-num | -n num] [-f file] [-t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS] [-R] [-adioxFw] [username..] [tty..]

Comment: What about `last -t 201701010000`?

Comment: No @Ravexina last: Invalid time value "201701010000".

Comment: Change the number to: `20170101000000`

Comment: It will displaying the output similar to last -a command.

Comment: We're now in June, sixth month ago is December, so you can use: `-t 20161201000000` to get all logs from December 2016 till now.

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting blank output. If I use 'last' command it is displaying only the details of current month, may be 'last' command can't fetch the details of user login of previous months. Correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: Read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/856199/access-to-logs-of-startup-and-shut-down

Comment: I gone through that link, but there also he mentioned like will get the details of last 1-2 months.

Comment: Is there way to get the details of the user login who logged in only today?

Comment: Your `last` command is a little bit old, you should use full date like: `20170628000000`, in newer versions you can do  `last -s today`.

Comment: Thanks! Can I update it to newer version or I need use latest OS?

Comment: It worth to upgrade the whole system,